# Missing gradle settings on Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, gradle

I'm trying to convert my .apk app to .aab with Android studio.
When I first tried to convert the file, I got a notice saying that I need to update my gradle. I didn't have gradle on my computer, so I downloaded and installed gradle version 6.9.1, and it still didn't work.
while following a YouTube tutorial I noticed that my gradle settings are missing the gradle projects section, where you can choose where from to use gradle.
can this be fixed? it seems the gradle I installed is not recognized by Android Studio, and the settings that allow me to change that are not shown.

probably important to note that I have no idea how to use Android studio, I downloaded it only to convert my apk app to aab so I could upload it to the PlayStore.

```
   [image - update notice][1]
   [image - gradle update that didn't work][2]
   [image - gradle settings][3]
   [image - gradle version][4]

   [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dlzf1.png
   [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/W4bll.png
   [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oaklh.png
   [4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ikwJ7.png
```